# how to "and" two conditions together in AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I wish to deploy an AWS resource using cloudformation, but only in specific environments. At the top of my yaml file I have two conditions defined below, where `Environment` is a parameter that can take different values:

```
Conditions:
  notInDevelopment:
    !Not [ !Equals [!Ref Environment, development]]
  notInStaging:
    !Not [ !Equals [!Ref Environment, staging]]
```

When writing the AWS resource, I understand you can specify one condition like `Condition: notInDevelopment`, but is there a way to "AND/&&" two conditions together such that the resource is deployed when the environment is not development, and is not staging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CloudFormation has [Fn::And](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-and). So you can do:

```
MyAndCondition: !And
  - !Condition notInDevelopment
  - !Condition notInStaging
```